# pgrouting - multiple travelling salesmen?

Tags: pgrouting, optimization

I've trying to solve a routing problem to optomise the use of multiple pieces of machinery.

Part A - I have two machines, and thirty distributed sites.  Ten sites require machine A, the other twenty sites can use A or B. A and B can work at the same time. The desired result is shortest path to touch all points once with the correct machine.

Part B - To build on the initial problem, B sites will take twice as long to complete as A sites.  Can I solve the problem to minimum total duration?

I have basicalyl no experience in these types of problems, other than some playing around with pgrouting.  All data is currently stored in PostGIS if it has any relevence, but I'm open to all options

Comment: As you formulate it, the fastest must be to let machine A handle all sites. A is faster and isn't restricted to a subset. Otherwise, have a look at our FleetEngine product: http://www.routeware.dk/fleetengine/fleetengine.php

Comment: Not sure I agree, but expect that is due to how I'm formulating the question. It must be quicker to have all resources working than to let one stand idle. To clarify - A & B can work at the same time.

Comment: OK, that can also be handled by FleetEngine. But it needs to be specified, otherwise 10 hours (A alone) would be seen as faster than 6+6 hours (A+B together).